# Stabilizer subgroup in adjoint action

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given $b \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, how can I find the stabilizer $\text{stab}(b)$ for the adjoint action of $SU(n)$ on $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ given by $Ad_U(b) = UbU^{\dagger}$ without using coordinates? The $SU(4)$ case is particularly important in my application.

Posted here after no answer on MSE after a week.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'without using coordinates'.  The stabilizer of $b$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ that preserves the eigenspaces of $b$.  Generically (i.e., when $b$ has 4 distinct eigenvalues), it will be a maximal torus.  Whatever method you use to compute (or 'determine') the eigenspaces of $b$ will compute (or 'determine') the stabilizer.

Comment: I meant to say that I'm not interested in writing a 4x4 matrix out and finding the relationship between the entries required to stabilize some $b$. I'm hoping to understand which group is the stabilizer, for example is it $U(3)$? Are all the stabilizers isomorphic for different $b$?

Comment: Clearly, they are not always isomorphic. For example, $b=0$ is stabilized by all $U$.

Comment: Of course.  $b=0$ has only one eigenspace, the whole of $\mathbb{C}^n$, while, if $b$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then there will be $n$ eigenlines (= 1-dimensional subspaces) and they will be unitarily orthogonal.  Then the stabilizer will be a maximal torus.  Pretty much anything in between can happen, and the stabilizer is determined (up to conjugacy, not just isomorphism) by the multiplicities of the eigenvalues.  (I'm not sure why you are asking this on MO, because this is basic linear algebra, far more fundamental than other questions you have asked about $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ in the past.)

Comment: I realize that this question is of that nature, but I got no answer on MSE which was surprising, so I wanted to check to see if nothing more complex was happening and I'd missed it.